Understanding AWS Glue pricing with Auto scaling enabled

I have auto scaling enabled and I have G.8x with 100 workers, and my job ran for 1 hour.
From the job metrics, I can see that the maximum number of allocated executors is 20.
In G.8x 1 workers maps to 1 executor. Each worker as 8 DPUs. So 100
workers means a total of 800 DPUs. So will I be charged for all 800
DPUs?

OR

As I have auto scaling enabled and the metric shows the max executors allocated for the job is 20.
Will I be charged only for 20 x 8 = 160 DPUs?


in Glue you are charged for the maximum number of DPUs used at any point during the job execution.
You mentioned that the maximum number of allocated executors is 20. Since each executor corresponds to one worker (G.8x, so each worker has 8 DPUs, the maximum DPUs used at any time would be:
Max DPUs=20 workers×8 DPUs per worker=160 DPUs
cost at $0.44/DPU-hour so it would be 70,4$
The maximum for auto scaling is not relevant to the cost as long as it's not reached.
An interesting article (section TPC-DS benchmark) shows example of calculation, from :
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/scale-your-aws-glue-for-apache-spark-jobs-with-new-larger-worker-types-g-4x-and-g-8x/

You can also use AWS cost estimator to do your cost simulation or use the Cost explorer for detailed cost and usage report :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/create-detailed-cost-and-usage-reports-for-aws-glue-jobs-by-using-aws-cost-explorer.html
Hope this help.

This is great. Just to confirm, I am looking at a graph in AWS Cloudwatch metrics, where there's 'Number of maximum needed executors', 'Number of active executors' and 'number of completed stages', and I am referring to the highest number in 'Number of active executors' as max allocated executors for this run. Is this correct?

Oh, Also after the run, there's a new value that's added called DPU hours, I can multiply that by the cost according to the worker type! Thanks!
